# Python compare is not returning match to 2 identical strings

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python.  I am executing Python code to compare a table's values with the values in a dictionary and set an error message if they match.  I have 3 table values so I perform this 3 times.  The match happens and works the first time, but the 2nd and 3rd times always fail to find a match.  I can't figure out why.  When I debug, the strings being compared look identical but the comparison fails and moves on.  I tried adding the str function before all the values but the same result.  I imagine the answer is super simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

Here is my code:

```
def validate_error_message(context):
for row in context.table:
    stored_message=''
    if row['userReference'] == context.storage['json_response']['fxRateResponseList'][0]['userReference']:
        stored_message = context.storage['json_response']['fxRateResponseList'][0]['httpReasonPhrase']
    elif row['userReference'] == context.storage['json_response']['fxRateResponseList'][1]['userReference']:
        stored_message = context.storage['json_response']['fxRateResponseList'][1]['httpReasonPhrase']
    elif row['userReference'] == context.storage['json_response']['fxRateResponseList'][2]['userReference']:
        stored_message = context.storage['json_response']['fxRateResponseList'][2]['httpReasonPhrase']
    try:
        expect(row['error_message']).to(contain_exactly(stored_message))
    except AssertionError:
        print("The status {} was expected but {} was returned instead".format(row['error_message'], stored_message))
        raise
```

Here is the value of the table:

```
And I validate the rate lock error messages from table
  | userReference                 | error_message                  |
  | user ref automation mulitple1 | Invalid payer data for payment |
  | user ref automation mulitple2 | Invalid currency for vendor    |
  | user ref automation mulitple3 | Invalid payee data for payment |
```

Here is the values of the dictionary (note that the responses can be in any order):
[image: response]

Comment: I don't really follow, but if the first condition of the `if` is satisfied, the two `elif` are skipped so they are never executed. could this be the problem ?

Comment: Are you missing an `iterrows`, i.e. `for row in context.table.iterrows():`? Just guessing you work with `PyTables`.

Comment: Thank you all!  I was able to find it based on all the ideas.  Simple comparison mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one.
if some thing was wrong with the object you can find which one it is and debug it

```py
for item in context.storage['json_response']['fxRateResponseList']:
    user_reference = item.get("userReference")
    http_reasonphrase = item.get("httpReasonPhrase")
    if http_reasonphrase && user_reference && row['userReference'] = user_reference:
        user_reference = http_reasonphrase
    else:
        print("some thing wrong with this object")
```